# got some problems with anonymous classes

Tags: java

i was trying to create an anon class in java

```
class myClass {

   int x = 10;

 }



public class Main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myClass myObject = new myClass() {

           public void run(){
               System.out.println(x);
           }
        };
        myObject.run(); //gives an error saying "method run() is undefined for the type myClass"
    }

  }
```

and it does not seem to work at all , it gives me an error saying that method run() is undefined although i created an anon class containing the run() mehtod , i am a complete java beginner , i code most of the time in javascript , javascript is the language i am most familiar with and i am trying to get used to java concepts so yeah this question might seem silly to alot of people here and i apologize for that.
thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your `run()` prototype inside your interface declaration?

Comment: Provide your whole code if you want to get help.

Comment: It is not defined in `myClass` which is type of `myObject` variable. Just like `Animal animal = new Bird(); animal.fly();` wouldn't compile when `Animal` doesn't define `fly()` method, even if it will be defined in `Bird` class.

Comment: this is the whole code and i got my problem sovled in the answers below already so thanks for eveyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the compiler doesn't know there is a `run` method, because there isn't one on the base class `myClass`.

This would work in Java 10+, using `var`:

```
var myObject = new myClass() {

       public void run(){
           System.out.println(x);
       }
    };
    myObject.run();
```

This works because `myObject` isn't exactly a `myClass`, but is actually specifically the anonymous class, which is called something like `TheContainingClass$1` (where `TheContainingClass` is the name of the class in which this code appears).

It's a bit weird because you can't actually refer to this class by name - only with var!

Or, in earlier versions of Java, it works if you don't assign it to a variable:

```
new myClass() {

       public void run(){
           System.out.println(x);
       }
    }.run();
```

Again, this works because the receiver of the `run()` call has the type of the anonymous class, not `myClass`; but there is just no way in pre-Java 10 to declare a variable of that type.

Comment: thanks alot for your effort typing this useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs since your compiler is unaware of the method `run()`

You could fix it by making `myClass` an interface, or by using an abstract method.

```
abstract class myClass{
    int x = 10;
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
interface myClass{
    public void run();
    int x = 10;
}
```

It should run. The problem here is that you don't have the run method in myClass declaration